# Putting python code online- confusion with my app.py script

Tags: python, web.py

So I'm getting into the process of putting some of my first python code online and I'm a little fuzzy about some things. When we assign `app` to `web.application(urls, globals())`, what is going on exactly? Also, the line `form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet=None)` is referring to the two input forms in my other script called `hello_form`, but what is its purpose here? We're calling `form.greet` and `form.name` on the next line I see, but those should be variables created based on user input, (yet we say `name = "Nobody"`?).

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet=None)
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

creates a variable named `app` and stores the result of calling `web.application()` in it. In other words, you create a web application object, and store that object in `app`.

```
form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet=None)
```

The values specified for `name` and `greet` here are the *default* values - namely, those used if no user specified values are provided in the request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I tried breaking that second line by changing it to: `form = web.input()` and it didn't make any difference. Also in my browser if I don't type anything in the first text box it doesn't come up with "Nobody"; it's just blank.

Comment: @ZCJ It's blank because your browser is still submitting a value for that form (an empty string). You'd have to remove the box entirely to have the browser not submit a value.

Comment: Then why would I ever put those default values in there? I'm putting them in there because the web.input() variable called `form` exists. Since the only way they could be shown is if I don't even have that box, why would you ever need them as a default?

Comment: Because it's possible to access your form processor via other means than through your form. For instance, someone could use `curl` to send an HTTP request with whatever they want in it. Defaults allow you to write robust webapps that don't fail in weird ways just because someone circumvents your page.